# How to view a GPG encrypted file securely?

Tags: security, encryption, gpg, pgp

When I decrypt / view  a gpg file it is:

- decrypted in the terminal / console and thus gets into history
- the decryption goes into video memory
- and into normal memory
- and into the swap (if not enough memory)
- and into the hibernation file (if you hibernate after loading) 
  ...

Basically when someone takes my laptop and knows what he/she is doing it's easy to get the dece

Comment: That's why you don't lend your stuff to people you don't trust.

Comment: There is a reason why one of the basic tenets of security is "given unrestricted physical access, all bets are off". Why bother with going through all that when they can just, for example, install a key logger and borrow your laptop again later?

Comment: As a side note the first point is totally false: stdout doesn't go to your history.

Comment: Linux has been able for years to use encrypted swap. It's completely transparent.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use full disk encryption.
2. Disable hibernation.
3. Always shut down your system when you're not actively using it.

Comment: Even with all this, a determined enough opponent could theoretically still compromise the system and gain access. I agree this is reasonable, but security is not an absolute, as I'm sure you know.